# File upload from a web-based application to a linux server

Tags: java, linux, upload

It seems that my code won't work after learning that the machine that I'll be pointing the upload path to is a Linux box.

My use case is, a user logs in to the web app, chooses a file to upload, then click upload button. Is it possible to do this direct from the Java code to the Linux server using appropriate `ssh` or `scp` libraries if there is any?

EDIT: Here's my current code.

```
@Override
public void fileTransfer(File uploadedFile, String fileName, String pathTemp) {

        File destFile = new File( pathTemp + File.separator + fileName);
        try{
            FileUtils.copyFile(uploadedFile, destFile);

                    String getTempFile = destFile.toString();
                    String tempPath = getTempFile.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                    File tempFile = new File(tempPath); // 1st file
                    String tempFileName = tempFile.getName();
                    String fileSave = getUploadPathSave().replace("\\", "\\\\"); 
                    tempFile.renameTo(new File(fileSave + tempFileName));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not copy file " + fileName);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you uploading the file to the server where your web app is running?

Comment: How exactly it does not work? What it the error message? SSH and SCP might not work for all client environments.

Comment: @RaviH The application server is a Windows Server 2008 machine, while the server where the files will be uploaded is a separate Linux machine.

Comment: @akhikhl I posted my current code. I used no `ssh` or `scp` because I thought the machine is not a Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is deployed at one place only (not mass distribution), the easiest way would be:

1. create samba share on linux machine
2. map samba share to logical drive on windows machine
3. do usual file copy with java functions.

**attention:** renameTo will not work between drives. You'll need to copy input stream to output stream or, better, use apache commons-io functions for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities:

1. If you can create a shared directory in linux and mount it under windows (see [Samba](http://www.samba.org). Then you can write to that directory like a local directory. File will go to the linux server.
2. Use a library like [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html) to upload the file from windows server to linux server.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things you can do:

1-> If you can program your linux server, then you can make a program that listens to user request on a port, and stores data in file. Then you can send you files to that port of server.

2-> The other way is you can use some sort of script to create ssh-connection to server and then you can just add file through ssh, but here your java program will not be useful.

I personally use my own program to share files between 2 machines in same network.
You can use it,if it will be useful for you: https://github.com/RishabhRD/xshare